# How to stop crouching in Breath of the Wild

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Link keeps crouching ... at the most inopportune times .. usually when I'm being chased.  How do I make Link stand up?  And how did I make him crouch in the first place?  I'm using the Wii U GamePad.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pressing the left stick makes Link crouch. I do this *all the time* during fights and battles because I get tense. To stop crouching, press the left stick again.

Comment: Thanks.   I didn't even know you _could_ press the joysticks on the Wii U Gamepad!   This also answers my other unasked question .. what is making the Scope appear mysteriously at times.  (Answer, I'm pressing the Right joystick.)

Comment: This is really annoying.  There should be a timer on this to make certain that you really want to crouch.